# Creating CF session variables to submit to pdf form by selecting row on datatable

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, datatables

I am using jquery datatables and coldfusion. I have a datatable that when a row on the table is selected all the information gets inserted into hidden textboxes. On the table is a pdf button. When this button is hit I am trying to figure out how to send my hidden text boxes as a form to set session variables and then populate a pdf with that information. For some reason though the session variables are not being set.

```
$('#ToolTables_processing_1').on( 'click', function () {
                $.post('redirects/selectedrows.cfm', 
                    $('#form1').serialize(), 
                        function( data ) {
                            //alert( "Data Loaded: " + data ); // Display information from link_to your_php_file.php
                        });
                <!---window.location = 'forms/exitinterviewpdf.cfm';--->
            });
```

**Selected Rows**

```
<cfset session.selected.selectedRowName = form.selectedRowName >
<cfoutput>#session.selected.selectedRowName#</cfoutput>
```

**exitinterviewpdf.cfm**

```
<cfset tempFilePath = "/mytemppath.pdf">
<cfpdfform source="ExitInterview.pdf" action="populate" destination="#tempFilePath#">

    <!--- Step 1 --->
<cfpdfformparam name="Name" value="#session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowName#">
```

Is this possible to do what I am trying to do?
Maybe it needs to be a submit button somehow?

Comment: Not sure - but there's no straight path from "session.selected.selectedRowName" to `"session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowname"` .  If you ented from the selected rows to end up in the exitinterviewpdf.cfm you will need to either set them into the session.exitinterview struct or use "session.selected" struct as the source.

Comment: sorry i just changed them thinking maybe it was that

Comment: there all using session.exitinterview.selected.selectedRowName

Comment: So you are populating a source file called ExitInterview.pdf and there is a field called "Name" in it?  Case sensitive yes?

Comment: but i cant see on selectedrows.cfm how to make sure its receiving the form variables

Comment: it starts with a datatable grabbing all fields in the database then the user selects a row. When that row is selected all the details of each column for that row show up in a hidden text box ( this is working correclty) then when you hit the pdf button it should send all those text boxes to be created as session variables so that I can populate the pdf form

Comment: as u see on exitinterviewpdf.cfm

Comment: this grabs a created pdf and fills all the variables in the pdf with my desired session variables

Comment: the only problem is for some reason these session variables are not being set

Comment: so i receive an `Element EXITINTERVIEW.SELECTED.SELECTEDROWNAME is undefined in SESSION. ` error

Comment: i duno if since theres no submit button that maybe thats why the hidden text boxes are not being sent over or what

Comment: and yes @MarkAKruger thats right when I take the session variable out and just put text it puts that text on the form

Comment: David, silly question - but is your code inside of an Application (something named by Application.cfc or Application.cfm with a name and session enabled?

Comment: Why don't you forget about session variables and simply use the form variables you are submitting?

Comment: @DanBracuk I tried doing that I think my problem is passing them through the next page because when I try to do a "post" nothing is happening

Comment: @MarkAKruger no its not in an application.cfc its in eitable.cfm I do however have this in my application.cfc `<cfset this.datasource = "dsn" >
    <cfset this.name = "ExitInterview">
    <cfset this.sessionManagement = "true">
    <cfset this.sessionTimeout = "#createTimeSpan(0,1,0,0)#">
    <cfset this.clientManagement = "false">
    <cfset this.loginStorage = "session">
    <cfset this.setDomainCookies = "true">
    <cfset this.scriptProtect = "true">
    <cfset this.applicationTimeout = "#createTimeSpan(0,1,0,0)#">`